# Convolution Neural Network with 1 input channel

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

I am trying to make a sudoku solver using a convolution neural network with pytorch. I am failing to implement the architecture with one channel. There are many great tutorials which deal with images in CNN but I couldn't find any tutorial for CNN with 1 channel input matrix. Any suggestions or help is appreciated.

Comment: There is actually no difference? Just set in_channels=1 on the first layer. Where are you struggling exactly?

Comment: Black and white images only use one input channel. So all mnist tutorials should be relevant. Here is one: https://adventuresinmachinelearning.com/convolutional-neural-networks-tutorial-in-pytorch/